# Decode JWT payload and header in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, jwt, cryptojs

The page below uses CrypoJS to create a JWT. Works fine. (I don't use the CDNs for CryptoJS because of security/firewall issues at client site.)

How do I decode? I can use, on the server side, JavaScript or VBScript with JS preferred. Given the token passed in with the HTTP request, I assume I'd decode the payload to find the claims, etc. and then simply compare the signature with a stored signature for this user.

When I try to do a `CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.parse()` of the "encodedData" variable, I get an empty string.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){var f={},g=f.lib={},q=function(){},m=g.Base={extend:function(a){q.prototype=this;var c=new q;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty("init")||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty("toString")&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},
r=g.WordArray=m.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=s?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||k).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,d=a.words,b=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(b%4)for(var e=0;e<a;e++)c[b+e>>>2]|=(d[e>>>2]>>>24-8*(e%4)&255)<<24-8*((b+e)%4);else if(65535<d.length)for(e=0;e<a;e+=4)c[b+e>>>2]=d[e>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,d);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<<
32-8*(c%4);a.length=h.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a;d+=4)c.push(4294967296*h.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),l=f.enc={},k=l.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++){var e=c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255;d.push((e>>>4).toString(16));d.push((e&15).toString(16))}return d.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b+=2)d[b>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(b,
2),16)<<24-4*(b%8);return new r.init(d,c/2)}},n=l.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++)d.push(String.fromCharCode(c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255));return d.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b++)d[b>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(b)&255)<<24-8*(b%4);return new r.init(d,c)}},j=l.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(n.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error("Malformed UTF-8 data");}},parse:function(a){return n.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}},
u=g.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=m.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){"string"==typeof a&&(a=j.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,d=c.words,b=c.sigBytes,e=this.blockSize,f=b/(4*e),f=a?h.ceil(f):h.max((f|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=f*e;b=h.min(4*a,b);if(a){for(var g=0;g<a;g+=e)this._doProcessBlock(d,g);g=d.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=b}return new r.init(g,b)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);
a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});g.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:m.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(c)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new t.HMAC.init(a,
d)).finalize(c)}}});var t=f.algo={};return f}(Math);
(function(h){for(var s=CryptoJS,f=s.lib,g=f.WordArray,q=f.Hasher,f=s.algo,m=[],r=[],l=function(a){return 4294967296*(a-(a|0))|0},k=2,n=0;64>n;){var j;a:{j=k;for(var u=h.sqrt(j),t=2;t<=u;t++)if(!(j%t)){j=!1;break a}j=!0}j&&(8>n&&(m[n]=l(h.pow(k,0.5))),r[n]=l(h.pow(k,1/3)),n++);k++}var a=[],f=f.SHA256=q.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new g.init(m.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(c,d){for(var b=this._hash.words,e=b[0],f=b[1],g=b[2],j=b[3],h=b[4],m=b[5],n=b[6],q=b[7],p=0;64>p;p++){if(16>p)a[p]=
c[d+p]|0;else{var k=a[p-15],l=a[p-2];a[p]=((k<<25|k>>>7)^(k<<14|k>>>18)^k>>>3)+a[p-7]+((l<<15|l>>>17)^(l<<13|l>>>19)^l>>>10)+a[p-16]}k=q+((h<<26|h>>>6)^(h<<21|h>>>11)^(h<<7|h>>>25))+(h&m^~h&n)+r[p]+a[p];l=((e<<30|e>>>2)^(e<<19|e>>>13)^(e<<10|e>>>22))+(e&f^e&g^f&g);q=n;n=m;m=h;h=j+k|0;j=g;g=f;f=e;e=k+l|0}b[0]=b[0]+e|0;b[1]=b[1]+f|0;b[2]=b[2]+g|0;b[3]=b[3]+j|0;b[4]=b[4]+h|0;b[5]=b[5]+m|0;b[6]=b[6]+n|0;b[7]=b[7]+q|0},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this._data,d=a.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*a.sigBytes;
d[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32;d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+14]=h.floor(b/4294967296);d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;a.sigBytes=4*d.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var a=q.clone.call(this);a._hash=this._hash.clone();return a}});s.SHA256=q._createHelper(f);s.HmacSHA256=q._createHmacHelper(f)})(Math);
(function(){var h=CryptoJS,s=h.enc.Utf8;h.algo.HMAC=h.lib.Base.extend({init:function(f,g){f=this._hasher=new f.init;"string"==typeof g&&(g=s.parse(g));var h=f.blockSize,m=4*h;g.sigBytes>m&&(g=f.finalize(g));g.clamp();for(var r=this._oKey=g.clone(),l=this._iKey=g.clone(),k=r.words,n=l.words,j=0;j<h;j++)k[j]^=1549556828,n[j]^=909522486;r.sigBytes=l.sigBytes=m;this.reset()},reset:function(){var f=this._hasher;f.reset();f.update(this._iKey)},update:function(f){this._hasher.update(f);return this},finalize:function(f){var g=
this._hasher;f=g.finalize(f);g.reset();return g.finalize(this._oKey.clone().concat(f))}})})();


/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
(function(){var h=CryptoJS,j=h.lib.WordArray;h.enc.Base64={stringify:function(b){var e=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,c=this._map;b.clamp();b=[];for(var a=0;a<f;a+=3)for(var d=(e[a>>>2]>>>24-8*(a%4)&255)<<16|(e[a+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+1)%4)&255)<<8|e[a+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+2)%4)&255,g=0;4>g&&a+0.75*g<f;g++)b.push(c.charAt(d>>>6*(3-g)&63));if(e=c.charAt(64))for(;b.length%4;)b.push(e);return b.join("")},parse:function(b){var e=b.length,f=this._map,c=f.charAt(64);c&&(c=b.indexOf(c),-1!=c&&(e=c));for(var c=[],a=0,d=0;d<
e;d++)if(d%4){var g=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d-1))<<2*(d%4),h=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d))>>>6-2*(d%4);c[a>>>2]|=(g|h)<<24-8*(a%4);a++}return j.create(c,a)},_map:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="}})();



// Defining our token parts
var header = {
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
};

var data = {
  "id": 1337,
  "username": "john.doe"
};

var secret = "My very confidential secret!!!";

function base64url(source) {
  // Encode in classical base64
  encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

  // Remove padding equal characters
  encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

  // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
  encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
  encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

  return encodedSource;
}

  var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
  var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);


  var stringifiedData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  var encodedData = base64url(stringifiedData);

  var signature = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;
  signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, secret);
  signature = base64url(signature);

  window.onload = function what(){
  document.getElementById("payload").innerText = encodedData;
  document.getElementById("signature").innerText = signature;
  document.getElementById("header").innerText = encodedHeader;
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #222;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #bbb;
}

#header {
  color: green;
}

#payload {
  color: orange;
}

#signature {
  color: red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p>
  <strong>JSON Web Token:</strong><br/>
  <span id="header">  </span>.<span id="payload">   </span>.<span id="signature">  </span> <br />
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"When I try to do a CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.parse() of the "encodedData" variable"* - I don't see where you're doing that. Can you point to it? Perhaps you forgot some code

Comment: I didn't include it because I have no working example. However, I do believe what I'm looking for is "stringifiedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)" to get back the plaintext of the Base64 encoded strings.

Comment: Yes, you would. So, what's the issue?

Comment: The issue is I didn't know that when I posted; I couldn't quite figure out the syntax and was looking for help.